# Daily views of every video in the channel measured from the release date

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get the number of views of every video in the channel but measured from the release date for 90 days. I would like something like this:

```
ID, Release date, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...... 90 
Video1, 2020-04-03, 100, 40, 20, 10, ....., 0 
Video2, 2020-06-03, 100, 40, 20, 10, ....., 0
...
```

Is there a way to achive this?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using a combination of [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs) and [YouTube Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/data_model) requests.

Firstly, query the Data API to retrieve all videos of a channel from the [search endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

Set the query parameters to:

part:snippet
channelId:CHANNEL_ID

You will get a list of videos with their details as a response, among others the `videoId` and `publishedAt` values. This is what you will need for the second query.

Secondly, query the Analytics API to retrieve view stats of the videos as a video report (differs for [content owners](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/content_owner_reports#video-reports) and just [channel owners](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/channel_reports#video-reports)).

Set the query parameters to:

dimensions:video,day
filters:video==comma separated list of video ids
metric:views
startDate:earliest published date of all videos
endDate:latest published date of all videos + 90
ids:refer to  docs for your owner type

The scope you need for this query is:
yt-analytics.readonly

This query will return views for each video aggregated by day for the date span you provided. After you get the response, you can filter out just the first 90 days for each video.

Alternatively, you can write a separate query for each video with the specified start date and end date, getting a result that does not need to be filtered.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Advanced Tab in `YouTube Studio > Analytics` you can download your statistics as a CVS-File or open in Google Tables.
That's the quickest way possible.

Hope it helps :)